# github for windows bug all files deleted

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I tried to make a commit using Github for Windows. It said "Commit Failed" and now my git status looks like this...

All files are considered deleted or untracked. But all of the actual files are fine.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you “tried to make a commit ”?

Comment: @DourHighArch Github for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed `git reset` a few times and now it's back to normal! :D

I also deleted all `.lock` files in the `.git` folder, which I'm not sure was necessary.